# Using Google Document AI in .NET C#

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-dotnet-client, cloud-document-ai

I'm trying to process invoices using Google Document AI to get all the data from the document in .NET C#. I've added the resources from nugget (`Google.Apis.Document.v1beta3`) but can't find any documentation to use it in C#.
Does anybody has any information about it?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i can't find the info about this https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/invoice-parser#documentai_process_document-java to use it in c# V1Beta3. I can only find the Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1Beta2 in prerelease package.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to ask over on the github page, some of the packages are manually genreated.

Comment: @PedroSoeiro, I am really late to post but did you get solution for this ? I am trying to use DocAI for BatchProcess but facing lot of issues. specially issues with "DeadlineExceeded".

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation for Document AI has been updated to include information about the C#/.NET Client Library, including a Quickstart Code Sample.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp

Here is the full API Spec for the C#/.NET Client Library.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest